# JPA [EcliseLink]: Cannot change the type of an instance of parent A to subclass B In the single table inheritance

Tags: inheritance, caching, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I use Eclipselink-2.6 with wildfly-8 server in a JavaEE7 application.

I have three JPA entities A, B, and C.

B and C extend A.

I need to change the type of an entity instance myObjectId A to B, persisting the same id.

I tried to do the following in the **same transaction scope**:

1- Change the dtype value from "a" to "b" for the instance "myObjectId".

2- save A, flush, then clear cache, using evict, and using ((JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getIdentityMapAccessor().initializeAllIdentityMaps().

3- find by id the new object by the class b em.find(B.class, oldId);

This results in a class cast exception, cannot Cast Class A to B!

Any help would to understand this behavior, and to find a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use a different EntityManager? You mentioned clear cache with evict, but I would guess that it isn't by calling EntityManager.clear() - The A instance will be managed by the EntityManager cache and returned on all queries through it otherwise. Evict is generally done on the shared cache at the EMF level. I'd suggest committing the transaction changing A->B and then closing the EM before trying to read it back in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this and didn't work. I still got class cast exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

I edited the dtype of instant myObjectId from A to B, and merged it;
Detached the entity myObjectId.

Clears the cache of em using:
((JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getIdentityMapAccessor().initializeAllIdentityMaps()
Find the entity of type B of id myObjectId.id;

```
oldId = myObjectId.getId();
myObjectId.setdType("a");
em.merge(myObjectId);
em.flush();
em.detach(myObjectId);
```

Then, get the new Object b:

```
((JpaEntityManager)em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().getIdentityMapAccessor().initializeAllIdentityMaps();
B newEntity = em.find(B.class, oldId);
// Edited B as filling its fields...
newEntity = em.merge(newEntity);
```

Comment: This, other than detach, is the same outline of events you put in the question. What is missing is the transactional boundaries and EM context boundary - is the em doing the read the same em you merged into? Did you not have to flush or commit the transaction first?

Comment: I edited my answer, yes I flushed data before detach, and yes the EM doing the read in the answer is the same EM that made merge. I tried with different EM and it didn't work out.

Comment: A different EM won't work until you commit the transaction.